# How to remove default document style from an element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a div element which shows some text as popup. But the problem is when i create the element using javascript, the div already contains the default style which is defined in document style sheet or external css. Like for example:

```
popup = document.createElement("div");
popup.setAttribute("id","myElement");
popup.style.left = "100px";
popup.style.top = "100px";
popup.style.width = "100px";
popup.style.height = "100px";
document.body.appendChild(popup);
```

and now when it shows up, it already has colors, borders etc because in css there is this div style which is being applied on this element. I want it to not inherit anything which is defined for the document itself, how can i do that, or may be overwrite the original style??

Comment: You have to manually overwrite all style attributes which are significant.

Comment: Oh this does not sound a good idea, there could be so many like backgrounds, images, hover effects, borders, colors.... so that means i have to overwrite all, there is no other way?

Comment: Notice my addition of *"significant"**. There are several style properties, but only a few of them are meaningful in your case.

Comment: "there is this div style which is being applied on this element" - do you mean you have `#myElement{...}` or `div{...}` in you css

Comment: yes the div or any other sub forms of this div like hover etc and also default text properties defined by standard html,body {} etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## So I made something like this. It may not be ideal solution but it atleast does what i wanted:

```
function displayMenu(){ 
    var popup;

    //see if there is already default style defined in the document
    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    var size = styleSheets.length;
    var cssRules = new Array();
    var rules = "";
    var css, len, st, sp;

    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        cssRules[i] = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        for (j=0;j<cssRules[i].length;j++){
            if(cssRules[i][j].cssText.search(/div/i) != -1){
                css = cssRules[i][j].cssText;
                css = css.substr(((css.search("{"))+1),((css.search("}"))-(((css.search("{"))+1))));

                if((css.search("{") == -1) && (css.search("}") == -1)) {
                    //no of css-properties in this specific rule
                    len = css.split(";").length - 1;

                    for (k=0;k<len;k++){
                        st = css.search(";") + 1;
                        rules += css.substr(0,(css.substr(0,st).search(":")+1)) + "0\n";
                        css = css.substr(st);                       
                    }

                } else {} //ignore this rule
            }
        }
    }

    var reset = '.myStyle { '+ rules +' }\n';

    //now create a css Class which overwrite default document properties for this <div> element
    var myStyle = document.createElement('style');
    myStyle.type = 'text/css';
    //TODO: should be replaced with style from arguments
    myStyle.innerHTML = reset;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myStyle);

    //start creating the popup menu:
    var popup;
    popup = document.createElement("div");
    popup.setAttribute("id","guide_popup");
    popup.setAttribute("class","myStyle");

    //now define own style rules: (All basic properties need to be defined as there is none by defualt now)
    popup.style.top = top;
    popup.style.left = left;
    popup.style.width = width;
    popup.style.height = height;
    popup.style.zIndex = index;

    //TODO: should be replaced with str in aruguments
    var popup_text = document.createTextNode("This is my sample text");
    popup.appendChild(popup_text);

    //finally process the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(popup);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve this is to override all of the available properties set with the css in this document. But with JavaScript is a lot of work.

Better way is to add an id or class to the newly created element. The style should have all of the properties that are applicable for the type of element you are creating. If you miss a property it will be set from the present css.

Answer (score 0):

I would give these new `div`s a specific class name and link a custom stylesheet that resets all properties for that class to the desired defaults (ensuring that the linked styles have the necessary precedence in the cascade). Moving this reset into your JavaScript sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: the idea is the same as mentioned by Rob. Problem is even for new style sheet i do not know exaclty which elements i need to overwrite, so that is lot of work. Because even with new style, all those which are not overwritten would still be applied